# Python create new column and store data in .CSV file

Tags: python, csv, io, text-files, counter

I have stacked in my Python script where I try to open .txt files, make list of words from that file, count how many times word appear (Counter) and put it in .csv file. My files got names from 1870.txt - 1892 (1871,1872,1873..1892.txt). Everything from there works, but I want for each file to put in next column.

```
def putInExcel(outputt):
    i = 1790
    while i < 1892:
        inputt = str(i) + '.txt' #Making text file name

        writefile = open(outputt)
        writer = csv.writer(writefile)

        with open(inputt) as file:      #Separating each word and storing in list
            text = file.read().lower()
            text = re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", text)
            words = list(text.split())

            for word in words:
                cnt[word] += 1
            for key, count in cnt.iteritems(): #De-dent this block
                writer.writerow([key,count]) #Output both the key and the count

        writefile.close() 
        i = i+1
```

This script is working but it stores all in one column.
Does anybody have some idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a single table that contains columns for each year/filename. In each column, you want a numeric frequency count. The leftmost column would be the words themselves:

```
____     | 1790 | 1791 | 1792 | ...
Aachen       1      1     2
aardvark     1      0     0
aardwolf     0      1     0
abacus       1      2     2
acrimony     2      2     2
   :
```

You have a fairly simple script now, that doesn't have to worry about interactions between different data sets. When you try to deal with more than one input list, you will have to "unify" them somehow. That's why I show some entries with `0` in the example.

My suggestion would be to maintain a master `set` or `dictionary` of all the words seen. This will be the leftmost column when you are done.

For each year/input file, you can keep separate counts. You can organize them as two parallel lists: the year/filename, and the dictionary of counts:

```
All_words = set()
Headers = []     # 1791, 1792, ...
Word_counts = [] # {'a':1, 'baa':2}, {'a':1, 'abacus': 1}, ...
```

Now when you loop over the files, add the filename and an empty dictionary to the headers/counts lists:

```
for ... 1791 ...
    Headers.append(year)
    cnt = dict()
    Word_counts.append(cnt)
```

Count your words as you do now. But when you count a word, also add it to the set of all words:

```
        cnt[word] += 1
        All_words.add(word)
```

Finally, when you are done, you will have to process the words in the same order. So sort the contents of `All_words` and use that:

```
row = ['Word\Year']
row.extend(Headers)
csvfile.writerow(...)

for word in sorted(All_words):
    row = [word]  # Left column is word
    row.extend([yr.get(word, 0) for yr in Word_counts])
    csvfile.writerow(...)
```

Comment: This is just what I am looking for! But I am trying to understand and to connect code with mine

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by '...' for ...1791 ...  . Sorry but it's hard to me to move from one code to another :)

Comment: It means "whatever you need to put here". I was trying to make clear what loop it was in.